# UPDATE QUERY - Sum up a value from form with value from table

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access

I've just started using microsoft access so I don't really know how to solve this. I would like to use an update query to add a value from a form to a value on a table.

I originally used the SUM expression which gave me an error saying it was an aggregate function.

I also tried to add the two values together (e.g [field1] + [field2]) which as a result gave me a value with both numbers together instead of adding them together.

The following is the SQL I'm using:

```
UPDATE Votes 
SET Votes.NumVotes = [Votes]![NumVotes]+[Forms]![frmVote]![txtnumvotes]
WHERE (((Votes.ActID) = [Forms]![frmVote]![combacts])
  AND ((Votes.RoundNum) = [Forms]![frmVote]![combrndnum]))
```

I want to add a value [txtnumvotes] a form to a field [NumVotes] from the table [Votes].

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as well formatted text.

Comment: Can you try with using Val()  function? Something like Val([Votes]![NumVotes]) + Val([Forms]![frmVote]![txtnumvotes])?

Comment: @Veljko89 is right: [Forms]![frmVote]![txtnumvotes] would be a string value and adding string to number would be handled as adding string to string. Use `SET Votes.NumVotes = [Votes]![NumVotes]+Val([Forms]![frmVote]![txtnumvotes])`.

Comment: @Veljko89 wow turns out the solution was so much simpler than expected. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the expected data type with *parameters*:

```
PARAMETERS
    [Forms]![frmVote]![txtnumvotes] Short,
    [Forms]![frmVote]![combacts] Long,
    [Forms]![frmVote]![combrndnum] Long;
UPDATE 
    Votes 
SET 
    Votes.NumVotes = [Votes]![NumVotes]+[Forms]![frmVote]![txtnumvotes]
WHERE
    (((Votes.ActID) = [Forms]![frmVote]![combacts])
    AND 
    ((Votes.RoundNum) = [Forms]![frmVote]![combrndnum]))
```

Without the specification, Access has to guess, and that sometimes fails.